# $USER not set ssh

Tags: users, environment-variables

On some of my debian wheezy servers there is a global variable `$USER` that contains the current logged in username and on some this variable is not set immediately at login.

How do I set `$USER` so it is availabe in `/etc/profile` on debian?

I try to send an email whenever a user logs in with the username:

```
/usr/local/bin/shell-login.sh | mailx -s "SSH Login User $USER on YOUR-HOSTNAME" your@email.org
```

`/usr/local/bin/shell-login.sh` contains:

```
/usr/local/bin/shell-login.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Login auf $(hostname) am $(date +%Y-%m-%d) um $(date +%H:%M)"
echo "Benutzer: $USER"
echo
finger
```

Which also has no output for $USER

Comment: Does `$(whoami)` instead of `$USER` work?

Comment: Yes that works, that will solve my problem, but the question is still there. Why does it differ on different servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace `$USER` with `$(whoami)` (a command that is built in on almost all Unix systems).

As for why `$USER` isn't set, it's [typically set by `login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html). But since you're SSH'ing into the server instead of using an actual interactive shell, the `$USER` variable is (and several other environment variables are) never set.

Comment: "never set"? But on my other server they are set

Comment: @rubo77 Does your other server happen to use a shell other than `bash`? Some shells, such as `zsh`, will set these variables for you anyway.

Comment: yes, it uses just `/bin/sh` that might be the differrence